# Using a user session to store configuration through Javascript

Tags: django, cookies, django-sessions

I need to use a session to keep a Javascript feature of the app. Each user will use this feature so I'm using `request.session` to store the Javascript value and use it on each template per user.

I have two questions:

1.- Why the `session storage` is not shown in the browser, but the `cookie` contains a `sessionid`?

2.- How can I use the `cookie sessionid` to store a value per user?

Comment: Er, because that's how sessions work. Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions)?

Comment: I have but I am looking for something that is not in the documentation. I need to store a javascript value through each view and that can be related to the logged user.